# Conditional initialization in most efficient and readable way

Tags: java, if-statement, initialization, java-stream, ternary-operator

What will be the most efficient way to initialize a Collection (in this example a Map) conditionally? Do you prefer one solution over the other in terms of best practices?

I came with three solutions and I'd like to ask you for your feedback or opinions.

**First:**

```
Map<String, User> userMap;
if (isNotEmpty(userIdList)) {
  userService
      .getUsers(userIdList)
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserDto::getUserName, Function.identity()));
} else {
  userMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

**Second:**

```
Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
if (isNotEmpty(userIdList)) {
  userService
      .getUsers(userIdList)
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserDto::getUserName, Function.identity()));
}
```

**Third:**

```
Map<String, User> userMap = isNotEmpty(userIdList) ?
    userService
    .getUsers(userIdList)
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserDto::getUserName, Function.identity()))
    : new HashMap<>();
```

Additional constraint here is that you need to validate `userIdList` for `null` and `empty()` before using `userService.getUsers()`

Comment: First and third ways are basically identical. Second way is minorly inefficient, but breaks effective finality

Comment: `userMap = userService...` got lost formulating the question. My favourite the **Third** solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'd drop the conditional altogether. If you stream an empty list and collect it to a map, you'll get an empty map:

```
Map<String, User> userMap = 
    userService.getUsers(userIdList)
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserDto::getUserName, Function.identity()));
```

Comment: The only question here is to the cost of the call in the empty list case.

Comment: Let's assume that you need to validate `userIdList` for `null` and `empty()` before using `userService.getUsers()`.

Comment: @Zychoo look into `Optional<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

> What will be the most efficient way to initialize a Collection?

I would go with `Collections.emptyMap()` as shown below incase if there is no `userIdList`.

```
Map<String, User> userMap;
if (isNotEmpty(userIdList)) {
  userService
      .getUsers(userIdList)
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserDto::getUserName, Function.identity()));
} else {
    userMap = Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

When you are using the `Collections.emptyMap()`, it makes the intent very clear and more readable.

You can have a look at the `Collection.emptyMap()` API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyMap--).

As others have already mentioned there is no difference between Option(1) and Option(3).

---

Nonetheless, you won't see any big difference in performance with this one thing (unless you do this in a loop). If performance is the real issue, then just check if there is any real bottleneck else where inside your application.

Comment: Be aware that `Collections.emptyMap()`  returns an immutable map. Depending on the further actions in the code, this may cause brakage.

Comment: When immutability is the case, this would be the best one. 

Additionaly. Is `Collections.emptyMap()` more efficient, since it does not create new object (which is costly) and does not reserve any more memory space?

Comment: @mtj which would be a good thing, as `Collectors.toMap(…)` does not guaranty to return a mutable map either. The fact that it does returns a mutable `HashMap` is an invitation to create code relying on an unspecified implementation detail. The best way to deal with this, is to use `Collections.emptyMap()` for the empty case and wrap the result into `Collection.unmodifiableMap(…)` in the other, to spot such errors as early as possible. If we need a mutable map, you have to use a collector taking a map factory.